# Multiple shared library dependencies with SWIG Java

Tags: swig

My shared object that I link in through SWIG depends on mq_open which is in librt.so  I am currently getting

java: symbol lookup error: /home/asdsad/eclipse-workspace/NGKSupportLib/Debug/libNGKSupportLib.so: undefined symbol: mq_open

I added

System.load('/usr/lib64/librt.so')  to the java program, but no dice.

Comment: When you compile your SWIG extension as a shared object you can link it to any other libraries you need to at that point. That's the simplest and most intuitive way of doing it.

Comment: thanks you for your help!